# Questão que faz confusão entre ASP.NET e EntityFramework

Tags: debate

Tenho notado que questões que na verdade são sobre [entity-framework](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework) estão com a tag [asp.net](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) e afins, como nesta:

- [Como Trabalhar com Views no asp.net MVC?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57402/como-trabalhar-com-views-no-asp-net-mvc).

Na questão acima, fica ainda mais confuso pois *View* no ASP.NET MVC é uma coisa... e no EntityFramework é outra... acredito que o OP está se referindo a *views* do banco de dados mapeadas no EntityFramework... mas olhem para o título... o significado deste título da a entender outra coisa.

O que fazer?

- pedir para o OP alterar a tag e o título da questão?
- perguntar para o OP se ele concorda em alterar e depois alterar?
- alterar sem perguntar?
- nenhuma das anteriores...

Comment: O pior é ler os comentários do AP na resposta do @CiganoMorrisonMendez.

Comment: @TobyMosque Exato... eles não estão falando a mesma língua.

Answer (score 6):

Isto acontece demais. Com várias *tags*. Este é um fenômeno comum porque as pessoas não entendem o que elas estão fazendo e/ou não entendem o funcionamento das *tags*.

As *tags* são para classificar sobre o que o problema realmente é. Ela não é uma forma de descrever o problema, ela não serve para jogar palavras importantes do texto, ela não serve para dizer todas tecnologias que a pessoa está usando, apenas as relevantes ao problema dele devem ser colocadas. Elas ainda servem para chamar atenção das pessoas que conhecem algo sobre aquilo ou facilitar para as pessoas que não conhecem sobre o assunto de um *tag*.

Um erro comum é o que você citou, o problema não é com a tecnologia que ela está dizendo mas com outra. Claro que alguns casos o foco do problema pode ser outra tecnologia mas ela está usando no problema uma tecnologia secundária. Por exemplo, a pessoa está com problema na formatação da data. Isto certamente não tem nada a ver com ASP.Net MVC. Até que ela esteja fazendo isto dentro o Razor e isto esteja causando um problema porque ele não está usando corretamente neste contexto.

Outro problema muito comum é o uso da *tag* do IDE. Muitas vezes a pessoa acha que o IDE é a linguagem que ele usa e que normalmente não faz diferença para o problema se ele estiver usando o Notepad. Ele não entende que essa *tag* deve ser usado apenas para problemas enquanto ele usa o IDE e tem um problema nele e não como o código. A não ser que seja um código de personalização do IDE, claro.

O importante é resolver o problema de forma certa. Não importa muito como ela será alterada. Mas não pode errar.

Diversas vezes eu não entrei em uma pergunta porque tinha uma *tag* que eu não conheço mas o problema nada tinha a ver com aquilo. Eu poderia ter entrado e respondido. Eu sei de algumas que isto aconteceu mas certamente acontece muito mais.

Se você entendeu bem o problema, acha que não tem um risco da pergunta estar confusa e não deixar claro quais *tags* devem ser usadas, tem certeza do que está fazendo. Altere logo. Se vai ficar na pergunta até ela ter uma solução, dá até para correr um pequeno risco, porque se você estiver errado você ainda poderá corrigir.

Se não tem tanta certeza assim, se há margem para dúvida, pergunte. Sugerir a mudança é sempre uma boa. Muitas vezes, principalmente entre novatos, ele continuará não sabendo o que fazer. Então se ele responder mas não alterar, faça você.

Como vai perguntar vai do contexto.

Neste caso específico a confusão é bem grande mesmo. Eu tinha certeza que era outra coisa. Ela tem um outro problema. Usa *tags* que são antagônicas. ASP.Net é o oposto do ASP.Net MVC. Claro que pode existir situação que ambas devem ser usadas juntas mas não é o caso da maioria das perguntas, ou está usando uma ou outra tecnologia.  Outro problema que é comum ver é o uso de [asp.net](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) e [mvc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc) que em 99.999% dos casos será um erro de uso da *tag*.

Comment: Então [tag:asp.net] e [tag:webforms] seriam tags sinônimas? Eu sempre enxerguei ASP.Net como a tecnologia subjacente tanto aos Webforms quanto ao ASP.Net MVC. Essa visão está errada?

Comment: Não diria sinônimas, elas frequentemente são complementares. Pode haver [tag:asp.net] sem necessidade de [tag:webforms]. O contrário já não é verdadeiro. Eu sempre colocarei ambas quando o assunto é WebForms já que pode não  chamar a atenção a sub-comunidade certa se criar muita granularidade. Muitas pessoas estarão atentas à ASP.Net mas não à WebForms. ASP.Net MVC não é ASP.Net. É estranho mas realmente é uma tecnologia totalmente diferente que usa o mesmo nome por marketing. E a versão nova desvincula mais ainda.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC, ASP.NET WebForms, ASP.NET WebAPI, entre outras, são todas montada sobre o ASP.NET, não é apenas marketing. O que acontece é que existe uma [versão nova do ASP.NET (chamada de vNext)](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/aspnet-5-overview) totalmente refeita, o que implicou em refazer também os dependentes... o WebForms é considerado ultrapassado e não vai ser suportado pelo vNext, enquanto as outras serão.

Comment: Então eu vou perguntar ao OP se ele não quis dizer outra coisa... e caso ele confirme eu mudo para ele.

Comment: Muda, claro, o mais importante é ficar certo. Então cite alguma semelhança entre o que você faz com uma tecnologia e outra. Diga onde tem uma sintaxe e uma semântica igual. O fato de uma usar internamente a mesma base não significa que elas são a mesma tecnologia, caso contrário C# e VB.Net são a mesma linguagem. Então usar o mesmo nome é só uma questão de *branding*.

Comment: Minha crítica é sobre essa afirmação *"é uma tecnologia totalmente diferente"*, o que dá a entender que ASP.NET não tem nada há ver com o ASP.NET MVC. O ASP.NET é a definição do pipeline, que contém `IHttpHandler`, `IHttpModule`, `HttpContext`, `HttpApplication` (global.asax)... ao usar ASP.NET MVC se tem acesso a tudo que o ASP.NET define, e mais aquilo que o MVC tem que são Controllers, Views cshtml, etc.

Comment: Mas concordo que colocar ASP.NET no nome dos outros produtos é marketing, o que eu quis dizer é que não é *apenas* marketing... ou seja, é marketing e também denota uma relação entre elas.

Answer (score 2):

Este caso aconteceu por uma questão de visão viciada. Normalmente desenvolvedores de Delphi e ASP.NET 3 Camadas vão direto para o ASP.NET MVC sem tentar entender os conceitos.

Por exemplo, o autor fala de trabalhar com uma relação de dados (que poderia ser uma tabela ou uma *view*) sem chaves primárias. Esta construção é um clássico do Entity Framework:

```
sistema_mobileEntities dao = new sistema_mobileEntities();
return View(dao.vcliente.Find(id));
```

`Find` é um método pertencente a uma classe chamada `DbSet`. É óbvio que ele está usando Entity Framework mesmo que não o mencione, e que possivelmente está tentando mapear um objeto de dados que já existe (o método é conhecido como *Database First*). Se é uma *view* ou uma tabela, para o Entity Framework, isto é pouco importante.

A resposta contempla perfeitamente o problema todo. O Entity Framework precisa de pelo menos uma propriedade indicada em *Model* para poder identificar unicamente um registro. É isto que faz funcionar o método `Find` usado pelo autor da pergunta: o argumento é o valor correspondente à chave primária que o Framework irá usar pra pesquisar.

Portanto, o autor da pergunta utiliza um framework da maneira com que bem entende, não formula corretamente a pergunta e ainda por cima coloca a explicação do básico do básico como "muito complicada". A meu ver, seria o caso de suspender a pergunta com o motivo "não é claro o que está perguntando".

Comment: Nos últimos comentários que fiz na questão, sugeri ao OP que a questão está equivocada, e sugeri uma alternativa coerente... mas até o momento ele não disse nada. Existem duas alternativas: fechar, ou editar. Se for para editar eu trocaria as tags `ASP.NET` e `ASP.NET-MVC` por `Entity-Framework`, e trocaria o título, afinal o mesmo erro pode acontecer em uma aplicação Windows Forms.

Comment: Mas eu também não queria fazer isso assim, de forma arbitrária... e eu também não sei o quão útil a questão é mesmo estando errada. Tipo, para alguém procura no Google, algo sobre "asp.net mvc" e "view" seria interessante achar algo que na verdade é relacionado ao entity-framework... talvez essa pessoa esteja igualmente equivocada. A questão é **questões com conceitos errados devem ser mantidas erradas, para que o equivoco possa ser explicado?** ou devem ser concertadas, pois o SOPT não deve servir de "guia contra equívocos"?

Comment: @MiguelAngelo Foi o que tentei fazer: dar uma resposta que pudesse corrigir o conceito. Não sei se tive muito êxito nisso. A ideia de manter é interessante justamente pra evitar que outras pessoas sigam pelo mesmo caminho e pelo menos procurem se interessar pelo conceito. Mencionar as tags pode ser útil neste caso.

Comment: Fiz uma edição no título e nas tags. Acho que não deturpa o que o autor quis dizer (seus equívocos), mas elimina a ambiguidade. O que acha, @MiguelAngelo?

Comment: @bfavaretto Assim está bem melhor. Se voltar a ver questões equivocadas, vou me lembrar da forma como você fez com esta, de focar em corrigir a ambiguidade.